# Showing a "Your request is in progress" in PHP and redirecting to a different page after completed

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to figure out how E-Commerce websites display a "Your order is being processed" while billing a credit card, and then displaying a "Your order is complete" screen after verification is complete. Something similar to this can also be seen when applying for a loan through a major bank. After entering your information and clicking "Apply", it displays a "Your application is being processed" and then redirects you to a "Your application has been approved" page. Basically, I am querying two web services that take a moment to respond, and I don't want the user to think that the website is broken. I am using WordPress as a base CMS, but I have modified it to query these services.

Comment: You should use ajax to perform the request!
http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/

Comment: @Perroloco: Thanks for your prompt reply. Do you know if there is a WordPress-specific way to do this?

Comment: I don't know, but wordpress is done in php so you should be able to add your own code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In high level terms:

1. When the user submits the form to `getResults.php`, your application makes the appropriate calls to the services you use (and assigns it a certain id, e.g. request #n3n3gn)
2. It then sends a reply immediately to the browser, and the browser redirects to a "waiting" page
3. The waiting page polls another script (via ajax, let's say `resultsReady.php`) repeatedly, and if there are results, redirects to another page (let's say `showResults.php?id=n3n3gn`)
4. Profit